# Memory leak when invoking __iadd__ via __get__ without using temporary

Tags: python, memory-leaks, decorator, weak-references, python-decorators

trying modify a decorator *not* to use a `weakref`, I stumbled across the following behaviour:

```
import weakref

class descriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return proxy(instance)

class proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.instance = instance

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return self

class A(object):
    descr = descriptor()

def is_leaky(test_fn):
    a = A()
    wr = weakref.ref(a)
    test_fn(a)
    del a
    return wr() is not None

def test1(a):
    tmp = a.descr
    tmp += object()

def test2(a):
    a.descr += object()

print(is_leaky(test1))  # gives False
print(is_leaky(test2))  # gives True!!!
```

This seems very odd to me, as I'd expect both cases to behave the same. Furthermore, from my understanding of reference counting and object lifetime, I was convinced that in both cases the object should be freed.

I have tested it both on python2.7 and python3.3.

**Is this a bug or intentional behaviour?
Is there a way to get both calls to have the expected results (free the object in question)?**

I do not want to use a `weakref` in `proxy` because this destroys the correct object lifetime semantics for bound methods:

```
a = A()
descr = a.descr
del a   # a is kept alive since descr is a bound method to a
descr() # should execute a.descr() as expected
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two codepaths are not equivalent.

In-place add acts on *two* operators, the assignment target and the item added. In `test1` that is `temp`, a local variable, and the in-place addition is translated to following:

```
temp = temp.__iadd__(object())
```

and since you return `self` and `temp` refers to the same object, this becomes `temp = temp` and that reference is cleaned up after the function exits.

In `test2`, you complicated matters, since now descriptors are getting involved again:

```
a.descr += object()
```

becomes:

```
a.descr = A.__dict__['descr'].__get__(a, A).__iadd__(object())
```

so you assign the result of `A.__dict__['descr'].__get__(a, A)` to the instance attribute `a.descr`; the descriptor has no `__set__()` method and is not consulted.

**But**, and here is the catch, the `proxy` object holds a reference to `a` itself, `a.descr.instance` is a reference to `a`! **You created a circular reference**.

This reference keeps the object alive long enough to show through the weak reference, but as soon as the garbage collection process runs and breaks this cycle, `a` will be gone anyway.

Moral of this story? Don't use `__iadd__` in combination with a non-data descriptor; include both `__get__` *and* `__set__` because you need to control what happens when the result is assigned back.

Comment: Indeed, adding `gc.collect()` to `is_leaky` breaks the circular reference and causes `is_leaky(test2)` to return False.

Comment: Yes, changing test2 to have a.descr.__iadd__(object()) results in a second False.

Comment: WOW. This is subtle. Adding a NOP `__set__` to the discriptor fixes the problem. Thank you very much!